# Is LINQ To SQL's use of sp_executesql performant?

Tags: t-sql, linq-to-sql

As far as I know, if I put some `where` clause there, I can see the SQL Server Profiler shows the statement was using `sq_executesql`; is that a good way?

The reason I am asking is because my supervisor believes `sp_executesql` reuses the SQL statements and minimize performance issue.

How do I address her concern about performance issue on LINQ To SQL?

Comment: Why on earth do you want to do that?

Comment: Please also tell us more about why you need this and may be there a better solution too.

Comment: @user: I change the title of your question to match what you're actually asking. Previously you said you wanted to **force** something, when really the body of the question didn't say anything about forcing anything.

Comment: If you're going to do that, why are you using Linq to SQL?

Answer (score 0):

Linq-to-Sql is not good for high performance: it optimizes for convenience.  If you need high performance, go with the standard ADO.NET Connection, Command, and DataReader.

Having said that, performance is irrelevant for the majority of applications, so Linq-to-Sql is veyr useful. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking if sq_executesql is performant, then yes it is. From MSDN's article on [sp_executesql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx):

> sp_executesql can be used instead of
>   stored procedures to execute a
>   Transact-SQL statement many times when
>   the change in parameter values to the
>   statement is the only variation.
>   Because the Transact-SQL statement
>   itself remains constant and only the
>   parameter values change, the **SQL
>   Server query optimizer is likely to
>   reuse the execution plan** it generates
>   for the first execution.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit tough to answer this as you're asking two things.  Even if all things were equal, Linq to SQL is not as flexible as creating POCO - which once you pay the price, is the better performing way to access your data (most lightweight, fast, and flexible).  This is what **Andomar** suggests with a DataReader.  If you're asking about using `sq_executesql` vs concatenating a string to send to your command, then **EddieGroves** has that answer.  I'd only like to add that `sq_executesql` is more secure since you'll add your variables as parameters to the call - less chance for a SQL injection.  Concatenating the strings would also force SQL to compile the statement every time (so it's slower).  If you're comparing `sq_executesql` to CRUD stored procedures, then you're right.  CRUD would perform better and also take care of the potential SQL injections.  SQL server would compile the stored procedures once.